# Create a copy of NSOperation in the failure block of same operation

Tags: afnetworking, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

Is there a way to start an identical NSOperation when the currently executing NSOperation finishes executing.

I am trying to download a set of files using AFDownloadRequestOperation (a sub-class of AFHTTPRequestOperation) with maxConcurrency set as 1. If a download fails due to intermittent availability of the server, the code reaches failure block. I would then want to add a copy of this current operation to the operation queue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can copy it by doing:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *newOperation = [oldOperation copy];
```

Note these caveats from the documentation:

> - `-copy` and `-copyWithZone:` return a new operation with the `NSURLRequest` of the original. So rather than an exact copy of the
>     operation at that particular instant, the copying mechanism returns a
>     completely new instance, which can be useful for retrying operations.
> - A copy of an operation will not include the `outputStream` of the original.
> - Operation copies do not include `completionBlock`, as it often strongly captures a reference to `self`, which would otherwise have
>     the unintuitive side-effect of pointing to the *original* operation
>     when copied.

The most important thing to note is that you'll need to reset your completion blocks after you make a copy.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, worth a try.